# MySQL - Date - Timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp

My table has the below mentioned timestamp
Outcome required: data between 1997 and 1999 morning times i.e. (12:00:01 to 11:59:59)

```
1997-09-22 18:02:38
1997-10-15 01:26:11
1997-11-03 02:42:40
1997-10-15 01:25:19
1999-10-15 01:25:19
1999-10-15 23:25:19
1998-03-12 20:15:12
1998-02-13 23:52:53
1997-09-23 23:26:01
2000-09-23 23:26:01
```

I am trying the below query but does not give the right outcome

```
SELECT * FROM r WHERE ts BETWEEN '1997-01-01 00:00:01' AND '1999-12-31 11:59:59'
```

I can find the outcome by extracting hours and minutes separately but is there a way where the query is a bit concise?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL server..?

Comment: I am using MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract date and time separately to fetch the needed data.
In MySql you can use DATE_FORMAT method to extract same.

Read more here: [DATE_FORMAT(date, format)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Your query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM `r` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(ts, "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN '1997-01-01' AND '1999-12-31' AND DATE_FORMAT(date_time, "%H:%i:%s") BETWEEN '00:00:01' AND '11:59:59'
```

If your date is not in DateTime format then you need to convert your string/raw date to date time format using STR_TO_DATE method.

Read more here: [STR_TO_DATE(date, format)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `STR_TO_DATE` function :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM r 
 WHERE ts >= STR_TO_DATE('1997-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
   AND ts < STR_TO_DATE('2000-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

P.S: `ts <= '1999-12-31 11:59:59'` implicitly means `ts < '2000-01-01'`

Comment: It still populates all the data when I use H. If I use h my data set is empty

Comment: DATETIME can have resolution smaller than second, up to six decimal digits. There is a one second gap between `11:59:59` and the following `00:00:00`.  Which explains our preference for the form `< '... 00:00'` over the `<= '... 59:59'`  form.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to specify particular hours of day within the range comparison that spans years. We'd need to add another predicate (condition) to narrow down the rows that match the range scan.

We can use `DATE_FORMAT` function to get hours, minutes and seconds (formatted with two digits each)

For example, based on the stated specification (only times between 00:00:01 and 11:59:59) we could add something like this:

```
   AND DATE_FORMAT(r.ts,'%h:%i:%s') BETWEEN '00:00:01' AND '11:59:59'
```

But it seems really strange to be omitting the second right after midnight, and the second immediately before noon. (MySQL DATETIME can have resolution smaller than a second, up to six decimal digits.)

Personally, I'd identify "morning hours" as simply hour values between 0 and 11, like this:

```
   AND DATE_FORMAT(r.ts,'%h') BETWEEN '00' AND '11'
```

That will include "morning times" before 12:01 AM and after 11:59 AM. For example, these times would be included by this condition, but be omitted by the first example condition:

```
   00:00:00.555 
   11:59:59.023
```

The specification isn't entirely clear... determining whether these times should be included or excluded would help clarify the specification. I suspect the statement of the specification is somewhat jarbled, and we really want all "morning times" between midnight and noon.

```
 SELECT r.*
   FROM r
  WHERE r.ts >= '1997-01-01' 
    AND r.ts <  '2000-01-01'
    AND DATE_FORMAT(r.ts,'%h) BETWEEN '00' AND '11'
```

But it really depends on the definition of "morning hours", whether that first second after midnight is included or excluded.